# Any easy way to redirect a video file into a program requiring camera?

Tags: android, opencv, redirect, video, camera

To make inputting text into a CLI program easier, we can use file redirection. For example, we can use

```
mypro.exe <input.txt
```

instead of running mypro.exe and entering texts from a keyboard later, which is tedious when frequently running the program with the same input, like in manual testing.

We are developing an Android application detecting human face, eyes, shaking, blinks, etc. We want to benchmark our algorithm in order to improve it. So the same input is required, which is horrible for us to stay in front of the camera and repeating the same action for hours of time, for tens of times...

So I think is there a easy way to redirect a video stream into the program as a camera stream, without modifying the project code too much? Our time is limited and we can't specially develop a project to do this.

Many thanks to any recommendation!